# Why does my Spike Lego vehicle move only backwards, then stop?

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms

We are programming a Lego Spike vehicle in Python. The wheels move based on 2 motors. What the vehicle is supposed to do, according to my code, is pair the motors, move forward for 3 seconds, move backwards for 3 seconds, and then turn slightly.

What actually happens is that it moves backwards for around a second, and then stops.

My code:

```
from hub import port
import motor_pair, motor, color_sensor, color

class motorWheels:
    def __init__(self, speed, time):
        self.speed = speed
        self.time = time
    
    def setSpeed(self, speed): #Changes the speed
        self.speed = speed
    
    def setTime(self, time): #Changes the time
        self.time = time

    def pairMotors(self):
        motor_pair.pair(motor_pair.PAIR_1, port.A, port.B) #Pairing the motors on port A, and port B together
        
    async def forward(self, speed, time): #Main motors (A,B), speed between -1100 and 1100 #Time is in ms
        motor_pair.move_for_time(motor_pair.PAIR_1, time, speed)

    def reverse(self, speed, time): #Main motors (A,B), speed between -1100 and 1100 #Time is in ms
        motor_pair.move_for_time(motor_pair.PAIR_1,time, -1*speed)
        
    def turnDegrees(self, degrees): #Må testes for å finne hva "degrees" er i virkeligheten
        motor.run_for_degrees(port.A, degrees, 400)
        motor.run_for_degrees(port.B, -1*degrees, 400)

    def runUntilColor(self, num): #Will run for 1 second, each time in the loop.
        if num == 1:
            while color_sensor.color(port.C) != color.RED: 
                motor_pair.move_for_time(motor_pair.PAIR_1, 1000, 1000)
        if num == 2:
            while color_sensor.color(port.C) != color.BLUE:
                motor_pair.move_for_time(motor_pair.PAIR_1, 1000, 1000)
        if num == 3:
            while color_sensor.color(port.C) != color.GREEN:
                motor_pair.move_for_time(motor_pair.PAIR_1, 1000, 1000)

class Crane:
    def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height

    def crane(self, speed, time):
        motor.run_for_time(port.D, time, speed)

drive = motorWheels(0, 0)
drive.pairMotors()
drive.forward(1000, 3000)
drive.reverse(1000,3000)
drive.turnDegrees(360)
```

Comment: Seems you've got the speed reversed, try giving it -1*speed in the forward function

Comment: @DavidSiretMarqués, I tried it, but nothing changes, even if it did work, it should have then started driving forward afterwards, due to the next line.

Comment: why do you define the forward function as async? That might be what is causing all the problems...

Comment: @DavidSiretMarqués, Yea that's a mistake, but it doesn't work without it either. In this code i use " motor_pair.move_for_time(motor_pair.PAIR_1, time, speed)", and in this program async isn't needed. 
However, I tried with " motor_pair.move(motor_pair.PAIR_1, speed)" earlier, and on the next line I used sleep to allow it to move for the time it sleeps, at which point I had to use async. That said, neither of these methods work (with or without async). Only difference is that with async I can't even compile it :/

Comment: Did you check the documentation for the library you're using? I can't seem to find it...